# Program type already present in android studio

Tags: android, androidx, butterknife

[My project](https://github.com/CPPAlien/FileTransfer)

I migrated this project to androidx.

then , I changed this in  [project level](https://github.com/CPPAlien/FileTransfer/blob/master/build.gradle#L39) gradle file

```
    butterknife        : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0",
    butterknifeCompiler: "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0",
```

I changed to latest version of  butterknife .

```
    butterknife        : "com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1",
    butterknifeCompiler: "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1",
```

Then , I build my project.But , it occurs an error like this.

`Program type already present: butterknife.R`

```
> Task :app:mergeDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: butterknife.R","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
 Program type already present: butterknife.R
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
at 
butterknife.R
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:36)
... 32 more


> Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
 Learn how to resolve the issue at 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
 Program type already present: butterknife.R

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s
31 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 30 up-to-date
```

Why this error comes?

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Complicated to know about your issue (it's needed to review Gradle configuration) even I would like to recommend moving it to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding science ButterKnife is now deprecated

Comment: @ErikJhordanRey Can you give more information ?

Comment: deprecated -> https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Answer (score 0):

This error happens to me too, sometimes.
The solution that usually helps me is to delete `.gradle` folder from project and then restart Android Studio.